# unexpected error while activating env on unix

Tags: unix

```
1:/home/teipen>/opt/swe/bin/tn/tnproject checkin/unix
Bad : modifier in $ ($).
Can't open /tmp/newenv.4073
/opt/swe/tools/in/lotus-4.3.4/sparc-solaris2.10/bin/tnproject[593]
: syntax error at line 15 : `newline or ;' unexpected
/home/teipen: is not an identifier
```

It works for other users.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `set -vx` will reveal all. As JL's answer didn't help, I'll guess that there are now spaces in some of your filenames or paths that are not in the "other users" environments. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Tentative diagnosis:

- You use C shell; other people don't.
- The script `/opt/swe/bin/tn/tnproject` requires a POSIX-ish shell (Bourne, Korn, Bash).
- The script does not start with a shebang `#!/bin/ksh` or similar.

Test:

```
ksh /opt/swe/bin/tn/tnproject checkin/unix
```

Fix:

- Add the necessary shebang.
- Stop using C shell<sup>*</sup>.

If the diagnosis is correct, either or both fixes are sensible — both more so than either alone.

<sup>* Sea shells are best left on the sea shore!</sup>

Comment: I am not using C shell. I checked it using echo $SHELL, it's a /usr/bin/ksh

Comment: OK; it's good that you're not using C shell.  Is `/opt/swe/bin/tn/tnproject` written using C shell?  The `Bad : modifier in $ ($)` message looks like a C shell error; I'm tolerably sure that there's a C shell involved somewhere in this.  Have you tried `ksh -x /opt/swe/bin/tn/tnproject checkin/unix` and observing the output (diagnostics go to standard error; you might want to add `2>&1 | tee tnp.log | less` after the command so you can see what's happening.

Comment: Try: `export ICECREAM=chocolate` in your shell.  If it works, great.  If not, despite `$SHELL`, you're using a C shell.  It's good to know it works for some other user.  You may end up having to compare your environment with his (or her) environment, looking for the crucial difference.  I'd start by studying PATH, but I think the problem will show up without the comparison being necessary.  Does the script start with a shebang line?

Comment: whai I run this: ksh -x /opt/swe/bin/tn/tnproject checkin/unix syntax error at line 6 : `(' unexpected

Comment: Then I think someone has created a C shell script -- unless it's actually an executable of some sort.  Try `csh -x /opt/swe/bin/tn/tnproject checkin/unix` instead...and see if that makes any difference.  You could also add the output from `sed 20q /opt/swe/bin/tn/tnproject` to the question (if it is simple text), which would help us diagnose what's happening at the start instead of working blind.

Comment: when I run:csh -x /opt/swe/bin/in/tm_setproject enodeb/unix
if ( defined ( /home/tiepen/.kshrc{LOTUS_TEST} ) )
if: Expression syntax
Running the sed command is risky....others are using the same script as well.

Comment: I think I detect Perl, after all this.  `if (defined($ENV{LOTUS_TEST}))`...Please do as requested and show the first 20 lines of the code, for pity's sake.  We can't help you if you don't help us to help you!